# Limit of a series $\lim \limits_{x \to 1-0} \sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n x^n \sqrt[n]{\sin \frac{\pi x}{2}} $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Find $$\lim \limits_{x \to 1-0} \sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n x^n \sqrt[n]{\sin \frac{\pi x}{2}} $$

**My work**. I think that $$\lim \limits_{x \to 1-0} \sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n x^n \sqrt[n]{\sin \frac{\pi x}{2}} =\lim \limits_{x \to 1-0} \sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n x^n=-\frac{1}{2}$$ But I do not know how to prove it.

Comment: I think you're supposed to use something analogous to Tauberian theorem.

Comment: What does $x\to1-0$ mean?

Comment: @saulspatz It is another notation for $x\to 1^-$

Comment: @PeterForeman Thanks.  I always like $x\uparrow1$ or $x\nearrow1$ better.  The minus sign in $x\to1^-$ always makes me want to read it as "$x$ decreases to $1$."  I guess I'm in a small minority, but I always have to read it twice before I'm sure I'm reading it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sketch and hint:

Your guess is correct, but we need more proof. For $x\in [0,1),$ we can write the series as

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^n\left((\sin (\pi x/2))^{1/n}-1 \right)+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^n.$$

We'll be done if we show the limit of the first series is $0.$ Let's be reckless. The absolute value of this series is no more than

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n\left|(\sin (\pi x/2))^{1/n}-1 \right|.$$

Now $(\sin(\pi x/2))^{1/n}$ is closer to $1$ than is $\sin(\pi x/2).$ And $\left|(\sin (\pi x/2))-1 \right|$ is on the order of $(1-x)^2.$

End of sketch/hint.

Comment: Living dangerously... I like it ;)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

May be, you could use Taylor expansions around $x=1$

$$\sin \left(\frac{\pi  x}{2}\right)=1-\frac{\pi ^2}{8}  (x-1)^2+O\left((x-1)^4\right)$$ and using the binomial theorem
$$\sqrt[n]{\sin \left(\frac{\pi  x}{2}\right)}=1-\frac{\pi ^2 }{8 n}(x-1)^2+O\left((x-1)^4\right)$$